# Serializing class decorated with XmlRoot, error when used in List

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization, xmlroot

When i try to serialize a class element of type Test, it gives an xml with root element as "testing" which is set using XmlRoot.

But when I try to serialize an element of class Elems, Test element is serialized with root element "Test" instead of "testing".

```
[XmlRoot("testing")]
public class Test
{
}

public class Elems
{
   public List<Test> how = new List<Test>();

    public Elems()
    {
        how.Add(new Test());
        how.Add(new Test());
        how.Add(new Test());
    }
}
```

This the Output when Elems is serialized,

```
<Elems xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" x
mlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <how>
    <Test />
    <Test />
    <Test />
  </how>
</Elems>
```

instead this is what i need.

```
<Elems xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" x
mlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <how>
    <testing />
    <testing />
    <testing />
  </how>
</Elems>
```

Thanks

Comment: XmlRoot only applies when that object is the root - the outermost object.

Comment: is there any other way where Test class is serialized to "testing" as root in List?

Comment: you can use [XmlElement] or [XmlArrayItem] for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like this:

```
public class Test { }

public class Elems
{
    public Elems()
    {
        How = new List<Test>();
        How.Add(new Test());
        How.Add(new Test());
        How.Add(new Test());
    }

    [XmlArray("how")]
    [XmlArrayItem("testing")]
    public List<Test> How { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var elems = new Elems();
        var serializer = new XmlSerializer(elems.GetType());
        serializer.Serialize(Console.Out, elems);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works,but why is XmlRoot decoration not working when used in List?

Comment: @Rozuur, XmlRoot applies only to the object you are serializing which in your case is Elems. Any other XmlRoot attributes on child properties are ignored. That's how it has been implemented.